# Building and testing several packages in the same SPM repo

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I have a setup where I host several target under the same package. I'm working on CI solution to be able build and test those targets (lets simplify the case and talk only on iOS for the moment).

The issue that I'm running into is fully described and reproducible in this git repo - https://github.com/danibachar/SPM-Multi-Package.

Explanation:
I have a simple Swift Package, called SinglePackage, it has one Package.swift file, one class and one test. Inside my `SinglePackage` root folder I run the following commands

- `swift package resolve`
- `xcodebuild -scheme SinglePackage -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,id=4BE845BA-AE9E-4F53-B2FB-A5415C89950B' build test` (I got the platform from running the same command without the `platform` flag and checking what platforms are available on my mac. The scheme I got from running `xcodebuild -list -json`)

Everything build and tests great!

I have another Package, called MultiPackage, with one Package.swift file, and two folder/classes under the Sources folder. Each one corresponds to a separate target. When I run  `xcodebuild -list -json` I get several targets as expected

```
{
  "workspace" : {
    "name" : "MultiPackage",
    "schemes" : [
      "MultiPackage-Package",
      "MultiPackage1",
      "MultiPackage2"
    ]
  }
}
```

Now, I know I can use the `MultiPackage-Package` scheme to build and run tests over all the targets in the pacakge. But what if I want to test packages individually? If I run

- `xcodebuild -scheme MultiPackage1 -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,id=4BE845BA-AE9E-4F53-B2FB-A5415C89950B' build test`. I get the following error
  `xcodebuild: error: Scheme MultiPackage1 is not currently configured for the test action.`

I can still build those package while omitting the `test` sub command.

But still, what if I want to test each target individually? It seems like Ill have to generate the Pacakge.swift file on the fly, or separate and provide a Package.swift file for each "package/target' -

Id expect to have a way for testing individual targets within a Multi Target Pacakge.swift file.
Alternatively I'd expect to be able to make the auto generated schemes by xcode testable

UPDATE:
The only other solution I found was to create schemes manually for each target and put them under the workspace in the .swiftpm folder.
Id love to see those automatically generated

Comment: I posted it also in Swift Forums - https://forums.swift.org/t/building-and-testing-several-packages-in-the-same-spm-repo/63735 - awaiting an answer